# event components on page become unresponsive after page refresh

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

After I refresh my page(the refresh simply sets the events array to [], then refetches the data to be displayed on screen again), the event components still show, but become unresponsive to touch e.g. no buttons on the event card work and you can not swipe left and right on them. When the app first launches tho, you can interact with the buttons just fine.

The problem occurs after refresh EVERY time, but it also occurs after I go through my other tabs on the screen and come back to the events tab.

> this only happens sometimes but I thought it would be important to note.

I have tried to reload the component by adding a `*ngIf` statement in a parent div of the event card that checks for the event array being empty. I thought this would force the component to reload, but no luck.

I also made sure that the event's array first gets equal to [] before fetching for more data.

I also made sure that the data the event's array gets filled with is the same before and after the refresh happens.

HTML Code where the event cards are present :

```html
<div  class="cards" *ngFor="let event of events; index as i" class="final">
    <ion-item-sliding class="item-sliding">
        <ion-item-options class="item-options" side="start">
            <ion-item-option color="success" (click)="saveEvent(event.id)">Mark As Going</ion-item-option>
        </ion-item-options>
        <app-card *ngIf="event.eventDeleted != true" [id]="event.id"></app-card>
    </ion-item-sliding>
</div>
```

Some relevant global variables inside my TS file :

```js
limit: number = 5;
lastVisible: any;
```

This method gets run first :

```js
ngOnInit()  {
    this.fetchEvents();
}
```

My method for pulling events :

```js
fetchEvents() {
    this.fStore.collection('events').ref.limit(this.limit).get().then((events) => {
        this.lastVisible = events.docs[events.docs.length-1];
        this.events = events.docs
        console.log(this.events, "events")
    });
}
```

Problem occurs after this refresh button

```js
doRefresh(event) {
    this.fetchEvents()
    setTimeout(() => {
        event.target.complete();
    }, 2000);
}
```

Expected: After refresh, buttons should be interactive.

Actual: After refresh, buttons are not interactive.

Comment: Are just the buttons unresponsive or the whole app / is there anything still working after this happens? If for some reason angular isn't able to render the template (e.g. something was not defined that should have been) it tends to spam the log with errors and freez up the whole page. If there are no other components on the page and you forgot to clear your console filter (like me) it can take some time until you figure out that its not only the buttons thats not working anymore.

Comment: The rest of the application works. It is only the card components that start acting out.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like [ionic/issues/15486](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15486) which is basically:

> dynamically generated ion-item-sliding becoming unresponsive after removing elements from base array

The issues claims that this was fixed in ionic@4.1.0... Which version are you using?